Calculate year on year growth for each group in pandas dataframe
How to calculate the YEAR on Year growth for each group in pandas dataframe  say we have grouped dataframe based of month_date, name, alias
    date       name alia close ad_close
0   2011-01-01  A   c   100 --- 601
1   2011-02-01  A   c   202----704
2   2011-01-01  A   b   306----808
3   2011-02-01  A   b   409----909
4   2011-03-01  A   b   500----1001
5   2011-01-01  B   y   709----301
6   2018-01-01  D   y   810----400
7   2018-02-01  E   e   200-----600

Expected Output Dataframe
    date       name alia close ad_close  close_YOY
0   2011-01-01  A   c   100 --- 601 -----Nan (starting row of the group)
1   2011-02-01  A   c   202----704 ------(202-100)/100
2   2011-01-01  A   b   306----808 ------Nan(starting row of the new group)
3   2011-02-01  A   b   409----909------(409-306)/306
4   2011-03-01  A   b   500----1001------(500-409)/409
5   2011-01-01  B   y   709----301 ------Nan(starting row of the new group)
6   2018-01-01  D   y   810----400 -----Nan((starting row of the new group))
7   2018-02-01  E   e   200-----600-----Nan((starting row of the new group))

Not sure Pct change method is not resulting the close_YOY for new row rather its taking the prev groups value as well while calculation. Need the right logic to achieve the result?
import pandas as pd
df_data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['date','name', 'alias', 'close', 'ad_close', ],
                       data = {'date': ['2011-01-03', '2011-01-04', '2011-01-04', '2011-01-05', '2011-01-06', '2011-01-07', 
                                        '2018-01-01', '2018-02-01'],
                               'close': [100, 202, 306, 409, 500, 709, 810, 200],
                               'ad_close':[601, 704, 808, 909, 1001, 301, 400, 600],
                               'name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'E'],
                               'alias': ['c', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'y', 'y', 'E']
                           
                       } )
#converting to datetime format
df_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['date'])
#grouping the data
grouped = df_data.groupby(['date','name', 'alias'])
#year or year growth 
df_data['close_YOY'] = grouped['close'].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=True)).pct_change()
print(df_data)

 Below dataframe is not the expected one as the starting row in each group in not Nan, only fist row is nan
2011-01-03 A   c   100 601 -0.800000 - this value should have been Nan as it is the starting row of the new group
     date            name.  alias.  close.  ad_close close_YOY
2011-01-04  A   b   306 808 NaN

1   2011-01-05  A   b   409 909 0.336601
2   2011-01-06  A   b   500 1001    0.222494
3   2011-01-03  A   c   100 601 -0.800000 # should be Nan
4   2011-01-04  A   c   202 704 1.020000
5   2011-01-07  B   y   709 301 2.509901.  #should be nan
6   2018-01-01  D   y   810 400 0.142454.  #should be nan
7   2018-02-01  E   E   200 600 -0.753086 #should be nan

Welcome. Please take care to distinguish code and text formating using Markdown help. Additionally, dataframe samples are best shared copy-pasting the output of print(df)
